# How to prevent from "System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression" while mock ILogger LogInformation method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

`ILogger's` usage in my controller's method.

```
public class MetaDataController
{ 
 private readonly ILogger<MetaDataController> _logger;
 public MetaDataController(ILogger<MetaDataController> logger)
 {
  _logger = logger;
 }
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetSearchFields()
 {
  _logger.LogInformation("Received request for GetSearchFields");
  ..
  ..
 }
}
```

my test case method

```
public class MetaDataControllerTests
{
    private readonly MockRepository _mockRepository;
    private readonly Mock<ILogger<MetaDataController>> _mockloggerController;

    public MetaDataControllerTests()
    {
      this._mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
      this._mockloggerController = this._mockRepository.Create<ILogger<MetaDataController>>();
    }
    private MetaDataController CreateMetaDataController()
    {
     return new MetaDataController(this._mockMetaDataService.Object, this._mockloggerController.Object);
    }

[Fact()]
public async Task GetSearchFields_WhenCalled_ReturnsSearchOptionsMetaData()
{
            //Arrange
//First attempt 
     _mockloggerController.Setup(x => x.LogInformation(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()));
//Second attempt
    _mockloggerController.Setup(x => x.LogInformation(It.IsAny<string>()));

/* at above line of code getting the exception message.*/
     //Act
     var metaDataController = this.CreateMetaDataController();
     var result = await metaDataController.GetFeasibilitySearchFields().ConfigureAwait(false);

     //Assert
}
}
```

as mention in /**/ comment getting the below exception

> Message:  System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x =>
> x.LogInformation(It.IsAny(), new[] {  }) Extension methods
> (here: LoggerExtensions.LogInformation) may not be used in setup /
> verification expressions.

so how to mock exactly and prevent this exception ?

Comment: By not mocking the extension method, but only the methods actually implemented on `ILogger<T>`. Note that if you do not actually need to verify what's being logged, mocking it is unnecessary; just use a concrete `NullLogger`.

Comment: Read my comment, and the error message, again. It's telling you *exactly* which method it wants to see mocked ([this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.log#microsoft-extensions-logging-ilogger-log-1(microsoft-extensions-logging-loglevel-microsoft-extensions-logging-eventid-0-system-exception-system-func((-0-system-exception-system-string))))). The extension methods ultimately call this method, and this is the only method in the chain that's mockable. However, as I said, also consider `NullLogger` if you don't need to verify calls to the logger.

Comment: ooh yeah, got it now..thanks Jeroen Mostert.